# Upgrade to MySQL 8: Could not find any file associated with the tablespace

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

After upgrading from MySQL 5.6 to MySQL 8.0.15, mysql service failed to start and here is the error log:

```
2019-04-16T11:34:52.077516Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.15) starting as process 22292
2019-04-16T11:38:20.091064Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012179] [InnoDB] Could not find any file associated with the tablespace ID: 4294967293
2019-04-16T11:38:20.091090Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012964] [InnoDB] Use --innodb-directories to find the tablespace files. If that fails then use --innodb-force-recovery=1 to ignore this and to permanently lose all changes to the missing tablespace(s)
2019-04-16T11:38:20.191785Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2019-04-16T11:38:20.892939Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2019-04-16T11:38:20.893192Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2019-04-16T11:38:20.893958Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-04-16T11:38:20.894726Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.15)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

This was happened on Ubuntu 18.04 using the usual `apt install mysql-server`.

Now, my questions:

1. How can I find the missing file?
2. If could not be found, how can I know what is this tablespace and which database or table it's related to? I need this to measure the risk of ignoring the tablespace.

Comment: This happened to me, too. I haven't found any answer yet.

Comment: I ended up with restoring the VM to a recent snapshot and redoing the upgrade. This time the problem did not occur!